# inorder iterator for binary tree - java

Tags: java, iterator, binary-tree, parent, inorder

Here is my Node class:

```
private class Node {
    private int key;         // the key field
    private Object data;     // the rest of the data item
    private Node left;       // reference to the left child/subtree
    private Node right;      // reference to the right child/subtree
    private Node parent;     // reference to the parent
```

.. and so on.

This is the inorder iterator with next() and hasNext() methods:

```
private class inorderIterator implements LinkedTreeIterator {

    private Node nextNode;

    private inorderIterator() {
        // The traversal starts with the root node.
        nextNode = root;
        if(nextNode == null)
           return;
        while (nextNode.left != null)
           nextNode = nextNode.left;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (nextNode != null);
    }

    public int next() {
        if(!hasNext()) 
            throw new NoSuchElementException();             

        Node r = nextNode;

        if (nextNode.right != null) {
            nextNode = nextNode.right;

            while (nextNode.left != null) {
                nextNode = nextNode.left;
            }

            return r.key;
        } else while (true) {
            if (nextNode.parent == null) {
                nextNode = null;
                return r.key;
            }

            if (nextNode.parent.left == nextNode) {          
                nextNode = nextNode.parent;
                return r.key;    
            }

            nextNode = nextNode.parent;                   
        }            
        return r.key; 
    }
}
```

The problem is, it only ever prints the left nodes on the left sub-tree.
For example, for a tree with root node 17, left node 15 and right node 19, it only prints 15.
So it never enters a right subtree.

I'm guessing the problem is with the `else while (true)` portion, but I can't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see step by step what it is doing?

Answer (score 2):

You could try a recursive approach.

Something like:

```
public void printTreeInOrder(Node node){
   if(node.left != null){
      printTree(node.left);
   }
   System.out.println(node.key);
   if(node.right != null){
      printTree(node.right);
   } 
}
```

If you passed this method the root node it should print out the entire tree for you.

I hope this helps.

Best.

Comment: For inorder, the print should actually be between the two recursive calls, not at the end.

Comment: Right.  In order... changing that.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the parent field of my nodes was not being updated properly. Once that was fixed, the iterator worked properly.

Comment: If you were able to answer your own question you should post the modified code for the community or delete the question...

Comment: @MichaelQuatrani I don't think there was a code modification with what he posted. It was an issue in his tree creation process which he didn't show here.

Comment: @brimborium  Right. That's why I was suggesting he post some modified code in an answer, otherwise, it doesn't really help the community.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a stack with this helper method:

```
Node advance_to_min(Node r)
  {
    while (r.left != null)
      {
        s.push(r);
        r = r.left;
      }
    return r;
  }
```

The first node inorder is given by the call to this method on the root. Something like:

```
curr = advance_to_min(curr);
```

And then I would implement `next()` thus:

```
void next()
  {
    curr = curr.right;
    if (curr != null)
      {
        curr = advance_to_min(curr);
        return;
      }

    if (s.is_empty())
      curr = null;
    else
      curr = s.pop();
  }
```

`curr` and the stack `s` would be iterator attributes. `curr` would point to the current node in the inorder sequence.

The cost `O(lg n)` at worst case for each `next()` call (if the tree tends to be balanced) and the approach does not require parent pointers; so, it would have the same space cost than using parent pointers but only in the worst case